# Run a timer task on a specific day (1st of every month) using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We have a requirement of running a job on 1st of every month (time: 00:00:00 AM) exactly.
We are using Spring framework's *ScheduledTimerTask* to schedule jobs using delay and period properties. This class doesn't support running a job on specific date.

Can somebody suggest, how we can solve that problem using Spring and Java technology?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't have to run this job on a single node in a cluster you can use Spring Task, see:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

```java
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 1 1/1 *")
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute on 1st day every month @ 00:00
}
```

For generating cron expressions try [cronmaker.com](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Please be aware that if you use this code in a cluster it will run on all nodes.

Comment: the cron expression throws exception "cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 7..." because Spring cron format is different than unix (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887822/spring-cron-vs-normal-cron)

Comment: According to https://crontab.guru/#0_0_0_1_1/1_* the expression is not valid always.

Comment: @thinwybk Cron tab and Scheduled both follows different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Since v5.3 Spring supports macros which represent commonly used sequences. See: [New in Spring 5.3: Improved Cron Expressions](https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions)

In your case you could use:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "@monthly")
public void task() {
    // your task
}
```

which is the same as writing this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1 * *")
public void task() {
    // your task
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quartz Scheduler. It integrates great with Spring.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

Comment: Does Quartz add anything useful to what's already there with Spring? Just wondering...

Comment: @Lawrence I am not sure. I use Quartz but it may be an old legacy thing from some old times when Spring itself did not have these capabilities.

Comment: @peter.petrov, Does **@Scheduled** annotation support the expression for first monday of month?